# Tool to Prove a Context Switch is an Overhead?

Tags: multithreading, performance, playframework, threadpool

Currently working with Play!Framework and Akka. I often hear Scala Future is not efficient in the sense that each mapping is a new task pushed to a new thread. There is a potential problem where I am overwhelming thread pool due to this behaviour. I was wondering is there a tool out there which gives me clue that unnecessarily context switch among CPU bound tasks is causing latency to deteriorate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use YourKit to profile Play.  If all the time in your app is being spent in Akka's `Dispatcher` classes, Scala's `ExecutionContext` classes, or Java's `ForkJoinPool`, then it's likely that you're doing too much context switching.  In Play's performance test, we found (by accident) introducing one additional context switch degraded performance by 5% (though, this is a hello world performance test that does nothing, always take benchmarks with a grain of salt).

Comment: Dispatcher is a thread, so isn't all the time spent on dispatcher anyways? What I am looking for is how do we know we're context switching too much. I can reason about this in theory, for example if your task is purely non-blocking IO (ex. play.WS), then having many threads will slow down the latency of the request. But I need a proof, what do you look for to see to detect this specific behaviour? I do use YourKit as well.

Comment: Dispatcher is not a thread, it's a thread pool. Each time you "context switch", there's a lot of mechanics that go on as the task gets sent to the thread pool, queued for execution, taken by a thread in the pool, and executed.  It's in these mechanics that the cost of context switching is paid, so if you see all the time being spent in these classes, it means the bottleneck in your app is in context switching.  And I put "context switch" in quotes because usually people think CPU context switch, but switching between tasks on a thread is actually a different type of context switching.